# how to verify a digitally envelop signed XML file using openssl

Tags: asp-classic, openssl

I have a digitally envelop signed XML file which I need to verify can anyone tell me how to do it through openssl or classic asp

Comment: You should research the question a bit. Once you have researched it, then try some code. If you have problems with your code, then you should ask specific questions.

Comment: I tried this command

Comment: Openssl x509 -in certificate.cer -inform der -pubkey -noout >pubkey.pem after that I used this command to verify openssl dgst - verify pubkey.pem -signature abcsigned.XML abc.xml but it's showing verification failure all the time

Comment: Can u please help me  with this

Comment: If you need help with using commands, then you should ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). They are sites tailored for helping with commands in general (Super User), and commands on *nix (Unix/Linux). You will probably get an answer faster.